# php curl cannot find key

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to write a php curl script call an api, but the documentation (http://rest.ensembl.org/documentation/info/vep_region_post) only lists other languages and I am having trouble getting it to work in php curl. 
In the documentation, an example call (which I confirmed works) in command line curl is:

```
curl 'http://rest.ensembl.org/vep/homo_sapiens/region' -H 'Content-type:application/json' \
-H 'Accept:application/json' -X POST -d '{ "variants" : ["21  26960070  rs116645811 G A . . .", "21  26965148  rs1135638 G A . . ." ] }'
```

My attempt at replicating this in php curl is:

```
$session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL,'http://rest.ensembl.org/vep/homo_sapiens/region');
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type" => "application/json", "Accept" => "application/json"));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{ "variants" : ["21  26960070  rs116645811 G A . . .", "21  26965148  rs1135638 G A . . ." ] }');
echo(curl_exec($session));
curl_close($session);
```

The result I get is:

{"error":" Cannot find \"variants\" key in your POST. Please check the format of your message against the documentation"}

The problem seems to be with the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, but since the required argument appears to simply be a string and I am using the same string, I cannot tell how it is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote server cannot understand your request because it is delivered as:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

which is the default `Content-Type` for `POST` requests.

This happens because your code fails to set the desired headers correctly. The PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) explains:

> **CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER**:   An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')

Set the headers in the correct way and it will work:

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json"));
```

**Remark**: do not `urlencode()` the `POST` fields (as suggested by another answer); the data you send is not a query string.

Your `Content-Type` header says `application/json`, make sure the data you send is a correct `JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass string with white spaces as POST string. You need to urlencode it:

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode('{ "variants" : ["21  26960070  rs116645811 G A . . .", "21  26965148  rs1135638 G A . . ." ] }'));
```

Comment: Does this work on your computer? I put that into my code to replace the previous CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS statement (after adding the missing ')' on the end) and I am getting same error message.

Comment: I have not tried it, I'm typing on my iphone now... I will try when Im back at my PC in few hours.